# java not running in any browser

Tags: java

I have two versions of Java installed on my computer:

[image]

I have allowed java to run in the browser:

[image]

Java is running in command line:

[image]

This is the error I get:

[image]

I have also enabled scripting in the browser settings. I have restarted the computer and I have also tried uninstalling all Java and reinstalling it. I am not sure what else I can do?

[image]

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/748306/169038

Comment: @SurajRao:  Almost all modern browsers disable Java in the web plugin.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the info

Comment: @Makoto My coworker has the same browser and same java versions and it works for them.

Comment: Which browser are you using to run the 'uninstall' applet? What version of that browser? Certain browsers like Chrome or Edge don't even support Java applets.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the below settings(as shown in screenshot) is enables in your java control panel.

[image]

Comment: I have added the image to the question now.

Comment: As per your latest screenshot, both versions are enabled. Enable only the version which is to be active.

Comment: I have enabled now only java 8, restarted my browser, tested the page and it still says java is disabled/not installed.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to uninstall the lower version of java, make the browser to run properly. After that figure out the actual problem then install the lower version of java once again if required.

Comment: I have tried this already. I unsitalled everything. Installed Java 8. Ran the browser to see if it is detected but it was not.

Comment: Yes., some other user have already commented. some of the modern/latest browsers wont support java to run in browser. So Which browser are you using and which is of the version? Try once in internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Even though I am using a 64 bit machine, if I install a 64 bit version of Java it will not work. I installed a 32 bit of Java and now it works.